# C: removing new line/null terminate input string

Tags: c, arduino, embedded

In C I'm using this method from a serial library:

```
int serialport_read_until(int fd, char* buf, char until, int buf_max, int timeout)
{
    char b[1];  // read expects an array, so we give it a 1-byte array
    int i=0;
    do { 
        int n = read(fd, b, 1);  // read a char at a time
        if( n==-1) return -1;    // couldn't read
        if( n==0 ) {
            usleep( 1 * 1000 );  // wait 1 msec try again
            timeout--;
            if( timeout==0 ) return -2;
            continue;
        }
#ifdef SERIALPORTDEBUG  
        printf("serialport_read_until: i=%d, n=%d b='%c'\n",i,n,b[0]); // debug
#endif
        buf[i] = b[0]; 
        i++;
    } while( b[0] != until && i < buf_max && timeout>0 );

    buf[i] = 0;  // null terminate the string
    return 0;
}
```

The string that it is going to read is like this:
"111\r\n" (with a carriage + new line behind)

It is being printed out in Arduino using

```
serial.print("1");
serial.print("1");
serial.println("1");
```

Using the serialport_read_until method (char until is '**\r\n**'), I want to ensure that I am reading the entire buffer correctly.

Which of the following below does the char* buf look like in the end?

> 1) 111\r\n
>
> 2) 111\r\n\0
>
> 3) 111\0
>
> 4) 111

I need to figure out this part before I use sscanf method to convert the string into an integer correctly, but I'm not sure which to use:

`sscanf(buf, "%d\r\n", &num);` OR `sscanf(buf, "%d", &num);`

In addition, should I change the 2nd last line: `buf[i] = 0;` to `buf[i-1] = 0;` ?

Comment: Mmm, spaghetti! Who wrote the library, some pasta chef?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you should expect `111\r\n\0`.  Note that the condition `b[0] != until` is checked after incrementing `i`, so when the newline character is received and the loop exits, `i` points to the next byte after `\n`.  Then `b[i]=0` stores a null byte there.

Note that this code appears to have a bug: if the `until` character is never received, the loop will run until `i == buf_max` and then store one byte more with the null terminator.  So a total of `buf_max+1` bytes are stored, meaning the following code would have a buffer overflow:

```
char mybuf[123];
serialport_read_until(fd, buf, 'x', 123, 42);
```

Unless the documentation says that `buf_max` should be one less than the size of the buffer, which would be counterintuitive and error-prone, the loop termination condition should probably say `i+1 < buf_max` or something similar.

Also, since `i` is checked at the end, even with this fix, the code will still store one byte if you pass in `buf_max == 0` (but without the fix it will store two bytes).  So that's another bug.

The `char b[1];` declaration and accompanying comment is a little weird too.  It would be more idiomatic to simply declare `char b;` and then just pass `&b` to `read()`.

So if this is your code, there's more work to do on it.  If it's someone else's code, I'd be very careful using this library, if this function is any indication of the quality.

Doing `buf[i-1]=0` at the end would avoid the overflow, but would also mean that if the `until` character is not received, the last byte received would be lost.  It would also break if you ever call the function with `buf_max == 0`.  So that's not what you want.

If you're using `sscanf`, the question of whether or not there is trailing whitespace is irrelevant; `sscanf("%d")` will just ignore it.  You should have a careful read through your library's documentation of `sscanf`.  In particular, the way it handles whitespace is not always intuitive.

Comment: would like to check again: would `sscanf(buf, "%d",  &num);` suffice for this case (to ignore \r\n) or would `sscanf(buf, "%[^\r\n]", &num);` do the same function as well?

Comment: `sscanf(buf, "%d", &num);` would work fine.  `sscanf(buf, "%d\r\n", &num);` would also work, since the `\r\n`, being a sequence of whitespace characters, matches any amount of whitespace in the string, including none (again, read the manual).  `sscanf(buf, "%[^\r\n]", &num);` would not work at all, since it is expecting to store a string, not an integer.  You'd wind up with `num` containing something like 0x313131, or if the string was more than `sizeof(int)` bytes, you'd overwrite other memory.

Comment: ok thank you so much for the insight! much appreciated. (ps still learning C)